# MahApps.Metro Font Rendering is Horrible - What Did I Do Wrong?

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I've been using MahApps.Metro for a few weeks now, and I can't figure out why the fonts look so horrible. I'm just using Segoe UI and Segoe UI Semilight.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try setting TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" and/or TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType" in your main window xaml.

Comment: Well that was easy! LOL

Answer (score 1):

Joel's suggestion was the solution!

```
<controls:MetroWindow xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Cmc.Installer.App.Views"  
        x:Class="Cmc.Installer.App.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ShowIconOnTitleBar="False"
        BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="Gray"
        EnableDWMDropShadow="True"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        Height="768"
        Width="1024"
        MinHeight="600"
        MinWidth="800"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="{Binding Path=AppTitle}" TitleCaps="False"
        Icon="..\Images\campusvue_student_Icon.ico"
        Style="{DynamicResource CleanWindowStyleKey}" 
        RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
        TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
```